# Where is file in GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I got everything set up with VSCode, Git and GitHub and cloned a repository. I added a few lines to the readme.md and created a new file named demo.ps1. I committed everything and pushed the changes to the GitHub repo.

I see in the repo where I added a file named demo.ps1, but I don't see the file anywhere in the GitHub repo. Where is it?

Comment: What do you mean *"see in the repo"*? What's your `git status`? What's the repo?

Comment: I looked at the repo in GitHub. I can see where it reads, "added demo.ps1 and edited Readme.md" Where would I find git status in VSCode? The repo is myname/test - but it is private.

Comment: In VS Code, click the [version control](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol) symbol in the sidebar. But note that actually running `git status` gives output you can include *as text* in your question. Just because you put "added demo.ps1" in the commit message doesn't mean you actually *did*.

Comment: Yes, repo is an abbreviation of repository.

Comment: @WinstonSnyder, check on GitHub if the files are still missing because sometimes it takes some time. If you are really sure, you pushed it properly.

Comment: @maciejwww, Thanks. I'm even more convinced that I pushed it correctly. I created a new workspace and cloned the repository again. I see the file, demo.ps1. I made changes to demo.ps1 and readme.md, committed and pushed. Now I see the demo.ps1 file with the changes I just made.

Comment: @WinstonSnyder, sometimes, that happens with GitHub.